# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' ¿Cuales son los posibles errores?

Tags: javascript, html, c#, asp.net, webforms

Lo que hago es accionar un evento del botón y cargar los datos del gráfico en el control linechart desde el servidor y mostrarlos en el cliente, lo cual sucede que no se pinta el gráfico, y sale por consola este error

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

No sé que sera, ya que  me funciona cuando creo un proyecto nuevo, pero en el proyecto donde tengo que implementarlo no sirve, si tienen otra solucion de como abordar este problema seria perfecto

El método que carga el gráfico

```
    public void LlenarPrimerGrafico(string[] labels, int[] datos, string titulo, string tipoGrafico)
    {

        string chart = "";
        // Grafico 
        //Script 
        chart += "<script>";
        chart += "var densityCanvas = document.getElementById(\"graficoUno\");";

        //editar grafico letra
        chart += "Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = \"Lato\";";
        //editar grafico tamaño
        chart += "Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;";
        // DATA
        chart += "var densityData = {label:'";
        chart += titulo + "', data:[";
        foreach (var item in datos)
        {
            chart += item.ToString() + ",";
        }
        chart = chart.Substring(0, chart.Length - 1);
        chart += "]};";
        //LABELS
        chart += "var barChart = new Chart(densityCanvas,{type:'";
        //tipo sw grafico
        chart += tipoGrafico + "',data: { labels:[";
        foreach (var item in labels)
        {
            chart += "\"" + item.ToString() + "\",";
        }
        chart = chart.Substring(0, chart.Length - 1);
        chart += "],datasets: [densityData]}});";
        chart += "</script>";
        Literal1.Text = chart;
    }
```

El código desde el html

```
                    <div>

                        <div>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Campos Mas Famosos"></asp:Label>
                        </div>

                                   <canvas id="graficoUno"></canvas>
                                   <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Comment: En qué línea te da el error?

Comment: me señala en la linea 1 del chart js, pero no creo que ese sea el error ya que es solo un comentario,     /*!    ----------------esta seria el supuesto error
 * Chart.js
 * http://chartjs.org/
 * Version: 2.6.0
 *
 * Copyright 2017 Nick Downie
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/LICENSE.md
 */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me falto

```
<script>
function pageLoad() {}
</script>
```

no se pintaba porque en ningún momento llamaba a la función

ademas de añadir desde el servidor el registro del script,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "pageLoad", script, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

asp:literal no creará una etiqueta para representar su script, pruebe:

```
<script>
  <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</script>
```

Y claro quitando la etiqueta script de el string que esta insertando en su función **LlenarPrimerGrafico**.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, pero no se pinta el gráfico, lo que no entiendo, es  que me funcione en un proyecto por defecto y donde tengo que implementarlo no me funciona.